# sqlite backup memory database c++

Tags: c++, sqlite, backup, in-memory

i want to have some sqlite database running in memory.

I can load a file based database into a memory database,
i can do a backup of file based database but what fails is
backing up a memory database to a file.

I checked both samples, exposed here:
https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

I mean, i used these examples.
The result is always SQLITE_OK on all sqlite function calls, execept 101 
for

```
sqlite3_backup_step
```

in the 2nd example. To make sure there is no mistake, i checked the memory database having tables
and data. This is the case. Also, using the same backup function, works for filedatabase very well.

So far i could investigate, this line

```
nSrcPage = (int)sqlite3BtreeLastPage(p->pSrc);
```

in function

```
sqlite3_backup_step (sqlite3.c)
```

always returns 0. So the database has no "pages".

The file based database returns 35 at this point.

So it seems there is no kind of copy because no "pages"
given for my memory database; but this mem database definitely has tables
and data.

```
/// failing backup
bool    backup_test_sqlite_mem2(void)
{
    /// create a file db
    sqlite3*    file_db =create_db("filedb.db",true);
    if(file_db != nullptr)
        sqlite3_close(file_db);

    /// we now have a database file

    /// create an empty mem db
    sqlite3*    mem_db=create_db(":memory:",false);

    /// attached prior created file to mem db
    attach_db_test_sqlite_mem(mem_db,"filedb.db");

    /// check we have content in mem db
    do_select(mem_db, "SELECT count(*) FROM stock","rows in backup_test_sqlite_mem2");

    /// finally back memdb
    int ibackup= backupDb(mem_db,"memdb_from_attached_backup.db",nullptr);

    /// the above backup is empty
    return (ibackup == SQLITE_OK ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory database has no pages because it is empty.

An attached database stays separate, i.e., its data is not merged into the backup.

To backup an attached DB, you must give its name (and not "main") to `sqlite3_backup_init()`.

Comment: I know (as i described it has no pages), but what should be the conclusion ? My in-memory source database is not empty (right before backup, it is created with 1 table, 5 columns and 500 rows inserted) but the backup is empty: no tables, no data.